# What is this encoding / why are these .txt files not plain text?

Tags: javascript, browser

I am browsing [the deck.gl repo](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl). It ships with some examples with text files, for example [this one](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/blob/master/dist-demo/data/building-data-s.txt). These files have a `.txt` extension, but aren't plain text:

```
!OohmwFjqwbMg@[?ADKJYXF@^?N?FAD

=wnmwFvvwbM_@WNg@@@@C?C_@UA?AD@?Of@_@UTu@??BK?A??FUVP?@JF?AVP?@JF?AVPGTA?EL@?
=urmwF|swbM_@UFS@@BK?C@C@A@E?CIGA?GE?CIGA@CF?@ABA@CJ@@GR]Ud@wA\T?@DB?AXP?@DB?A\T

<aymwFnvwbMaAOKCA@OKPk@CCDKAADKAADKAADKAADKAAL_@fBjAIVCCEL
```

The examples also contain JavaScript files that look as though they are used to decode these files, for example [this one for the file above](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/blob/master/dist-demo/workers/building-data-decoder.js).

What exactly is going on here? I assume this is a way of reducing the size of the data, but why not just rely on browser gzipping?

And why use a plain text extension when the file is clearly plain text? And why have a custom decoder at all?

Comment: It's possible that this data is output by a completely different system and they had to write JavaScript to parse this input. Not everything can be JSON, y'know.

Comment: The term "plain text" is used as opposed to "binary". That data clearly conforms to such definition.

Comment: The real reasons for using this data format can only be explained by the creators of deck.gl themselves, if they did not already do so on their blog/github page. StackOverflow is probably the wrong place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a custom encoding that uses byte values to encode coordinates/GeoJSON features.

For example, this line from `/dist-demo/data/building-data.txt`:

```
!GqgmwFrhwbM}C}@@K@IBO@IlBh@BOBMn@PHBGd@KC
```

is decoded using the `decodePolyline()` utility function into this array:

```
[
    [0.00004,0.00001],
    [40.70541,0.00002],
    [40.7062,-74.01624],
    [40.70619,-74.01593],
    [40.70618,-74.01587],
    [40.70616,-74.01582],
    [40.70615,-74.01574],
    [40.7056,-74.01569],
    [40.70558,-74.0159],
    [40.70556,-74.01582],
    [40.70532,-74.01575],
    [40.70527,-74.01584],
    [40.70531,-74.01586],
    [40.70537,-74.01605],
    [40.70537,-74.01603]
]
```

which is substantially larger in JSON format.

So my guess would be that the main reason is to be able to use smaller data files that are still portable/cacheable. It's still line-based clear text, so it's diffable as well.

Also, these files are still compressible. I assume that a full JSON file is not only larger to begin with but also exhibits less favorable compression characteristics than this file. A quick test on `building-data.txt` shows a compression ratio of roughly 2:1 for gzip/deflate (139,089 bytes to 72,660 bytes compressed). The compression result for the same file in raw JSON won't be anywhere near that.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! I suspected it was custom encoding but wasn't sure.

Comment: I'm not sure either. Maybe they didn't roll their own, but implemented some existing encoding scheme. The `decodePolyline()` function looks custom to me, but take it with a grain of salt.